# How to empty list view on button Click in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have one listview which contains data comes from server...in that when i clicked on next button other conent from server should be displayed but insted of that listview append the new data with previous data...so what to do???

Comment: while setting the adapter you can just set the latest data you fetched, you can re-initialize your adapter with latest data

Comment: Whether u have array for listview??Then reinitialize the array..If u post your code means it is easy to explain to you..

Comment: data comes from custom list adapter......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your `ArrayList` holds both previous and newly download data from server...I recommend you to clear `ArrayList` before adding new data coming from server.To clear ArrayList you need to call `arr.clear();`

Answer (score -2):

Empty data adapter associated with ListView.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        List<App> apps;
    ListView listView;
    AppsListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apps_show_layout);      
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvApps);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

                b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    //Cleaning data source for list adapter
                    apps = new ArrayList<App>();
                    //Filling list with new data
                    apps = yourerverResponse(); 
                    adapter = new MyListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.app_row, apps);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } 
        }
}
```